# Turn the whole file uppercase

Tags: python, file

I am working on attaching a file into my code and then turning the file into UPPERCASE. Rn its just turning the first sentence of the file capital while leaving the rest lowercase I tried 2 different way and I put both just in case u want to see a visual (one stragery is in hashtag, while one in code). How can I make it that the whole file turn uppercase?

```
newFile = open ('tobe.txt', 'r')
new_file = open ('tobeUPPER.txt','w')

#for line in newFile:
    #print (newFile.read()),
    #wholeFile = newFile.read()
#upperLine = wholeFile.upper()
#print (upperLine)


for line in newFile:
    print (newFile.read()),
newFile = open ('tobe.txt', 'r')
wholeFile = line.upper()
print (wholeFile)
new_file.write('tobeUPPER.txt', "w")

newFile.close()
new_file.close()
```

Comment: Try: with open ('tobe.txt', 'r') as old_file, open ('tobeUPPER.txt','w') as new_file:
    new_file.write(old_file.read().upper())

Answer (score 1):

Open both files using `with`, which will close the files for you. Read the original file's contents, convert them to upper case, and write them to the new file.

```
with open('tobe.txt', 'r') as original_file:
    with open('tobeUPPER.txt', 'w') as new_file:
        new_file.write(original_file.read().upper())
```

Comment: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file. its saying there's an error as the file is closed

Comment: @i'msorry Is this the only code you're running? If you're inside both `with` blocks, both files will be open.

Comment: okok i understand would I need to say print because as of this moment when I run it it doesn't show anything

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
with open ('tobe.txt', 'r') as old_file, open ('tobeUPPER.txt','w') as new_file:
    new_file.write(old_file.read().upper())
```

Answer (score -1):

You aren't actually writing the contents of the file. Try `outputFile.write(content.upper())`.

```
import os

def test():
    os.chdir("C:/Users/David/Files")
    files = os.listdir(".")
    for x in files:
        inputFile = open(x, "r")
        content = inputFile.read()
        with open(x, "wb") as outputFile:
                outputFile.write(content.upper())
```